# How to check phone lock screen state?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to check phone is lock/unlock state from Flutter app?

I've used `screen_state: ^2.0.0`, but it didn't work for ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [is_lock_screen: ^2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen)

```
bool? result = await isLockScreen();

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    print('app inactive, is lock screen: ${await isLockScreen()}');
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    print('app resumed');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the package `is_lock_screen` a try:

https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen

As per the linked documentation, you can check if the screen is locked as follows:

```
bool? result = await isLockScreen();
```